# how to deal with UFuncTypeError?

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

While running this program i am getting this error :
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')

```
import requests
import numpy as np
username ='xxxxxx'
password ='yyyyyy'
years = np.arange(1961,1967)
for year in years:
    url = 'http://aphrodite.st.hirosaki-u.ac.jp/product/APHRO_V1808_TEMP/APHRO_MA/050deg_nc/APHRO_MA_TAVE_050deg_V1808.'+ str(year)+'.nc.gz'
    r=requests.get(url,auth=(username,password),allow_redirects=True)
    open(str(year+'.gz','wb').write(r.content))
```

Can anyone help how to remove this error? I am trying to  download a large dataset from website.

Comment: Try str(year) + '.gz' instead of adding together an integer and a string.

Comment: In a new enough python, `f'{year}.gz'` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should be

```
open(str(year) + 'gz', 'wb').write(r.content)
```